# AccessViolationException was unhandled error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, odp.net

Here is the error,

[image]

here is the code ,

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OracleConnection con;

            try
            {
                con = new OracleConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = "data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx)(PORT=1551))                   (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxx)));user id=xxx;password=xxx;";
                con.Open();
                message.Text = con.ServerVersion;
                con.Dispose();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
               // con.Dispose();
            }


        }
```

Comment: it seems like thread-related problem. such issues often happen when two threads are attempting to modify some GUI control.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, In my case it's just a simple GUI with test code to check Oracle connection. It worked in first attempt afterwards started giving this problem. How to fix this ?

Comment: @Rashi: Yeah, that's right.. but you're modifying message.Text. Isn't it a part of UI? If so, there is well-known technique of correcting thread&UI related issues.. Besides that, from my experience, exception like yours sometimes appeared in my Windows Forms application, and I have never known what was causing it:(

Comment: You obfuscated the connection string too much to make any guess.  Contact Oracle for support.